# Want to conditionally concatenate strings from a text file using C++

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
8284734746
pat monahan 
8284735406
pat monahan
8277059735
rolling stones black keys 
rolling stonesnprudential center newark njn121512 
8277167638
keith richards 
prudential centernnewark njn15dec2012
```

So if you notice I have an ID and a phrase in the next line OR an ID and TWO phrases in the next line. My goal is to have IDs in one text file and text (that belongs to that ID) on ONE line and saved as a separate text file. So I need to conditionally concatenate strings in my text file.

The code I have so far doesn't achieve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
   return( strspn( s.c_str(), "0123456789" ) == s.size() );
}       

int main()
{
   ifstream inputFile("title_desc_ids.txt");

     string line;
      vector <string> ids;
      vector <string> desc;

      while (getline(inputFile, line))
      {
          if (is_number(line))
          {
              ids.push_back(line);
          }   
          else
              desc.push_back(line);
      }       

      string full_file_name = "./title_desc_ids_all.txt";
      string full_file_name_desc = "./title_desc_combined.txt";
      ofstream output_file(full_file_name.c_str());
      ofstream output_file1(full_file_name_desc.c_str());
      copy(ids.begin(), ids.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(output_file, "\n"));
      copy(desc.begin(), desc.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(output_file1, "\n"));
  }
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: So, what part of your code is not working? It looks about right from my 15s glance at it, but I presume if it's perfect you wouldn't be posting here. Doing "spot the error" is much easier if you know what you are looking for...

Comment: @MatsPetersson If after ID, there are two lines of text, I don't know how to concatenate them. I know how to concatenate strings, I just don't know how to code this condition that IF there are two lines after the integer line, then concatenate those two lines, otherwise, don't.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Right now, if there are two lines after ID, they are being stored as two separate lines in my text file. I want them concatenated and stored as one line.

Comment: Chemistpp suggests a decent solution. There are other similar ones.

Comment: I'm taking a screen shot of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of IDs you entered as you input them.  Then the indexes will match up.

```
int IDCnt = 0;

while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    if (is_number(line))
    {
        ids.push_back(line);
        IDCnt++;
    }   
    else {
        if(IDCnt > desc.size()) desc.push_back(line);
        else desc[IDCnt-1] = desc[IDCnt-1] + line;
    }

}
```